# How can I have tooltips with HTML in them when CKEditor mangles <span>'s

Tags: javascript, html, css, tooltip, ckeditor4.x

I have been playing with the included `CSS`/`HTML` to implement tooltips that I can use HTML inside to enrichen them.  The problem is that the website where this is intended for has a CMS front-end that uses `CKEditor`(4) and `CKEditor` doesn't like `span` elements - it seems to duplicate them and move the duplicated one outside the `div`.  This seems to be a known issue/feature.

I don't have FTP access either so bypassing CKEditor isn't an option, and anyway I actually find the WYSIWYG quite useful, especially for tables.

My question is this:  Is it feasible to use javascript that executes when the page finishes loading that grabs the HTML from somewhere (I guess a string constant declared in piece of javascript) and wraps it in `<span>..</span>` and injects it into the page at the right spot?  I'm prepared to give it a go, but I thought I should check first if it's a hare-brained idea/it can't work/there are much simpler ways.

```css
.tooltip {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 400px;
    background-color: lightyellow;
    color: maroon;
    text-align: left;
    font-family: Tahoma;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 5px 5px;

    /* Position the tooltip */
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="tooltip">Hover over me (tooltip HTML is inside a &lt;span&gt; - CKEditor breaks this HTML)
  <span class="tooltiptext">
  
  <h3>Tooltip using &lt;span&gt; and allowing HTML</h3><hr>
  <br>
  <table align="center" border="1" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" style="width:80%;">
    <tr>
      <td style="color:red;">Label 1:</td><td>data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="color:blue;">Label 2:</td><td>data</td>
    </tr>
<tr>
  <td style="color:green;">Label 3:</td><td><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/47/5bzH6DGdLHw.png" style="height: 24px; width: 24px; display: block; margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;"/></td>
</tr>
  </table>
  </span>   
</div>
<br>
<br>

<div class="tooltip">Hover over me (tooltip HTML is inside a &lt;div&gt; - CKEditor doesn't break this HTML)
  <div class="tooltiptext"">
  
  <h3>Tooltip using &lt;div&gt; and allowing HTML</h3><hr>
  <br>
  <table align="center" border="1" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" style="width:80%;">
<tr>
  <td style="color:red;">Label 1:</td><td>data</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td style="color:blue;">Label 2:</td><td>data</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td style="color:green;">Label 3:</td><td><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/47/5bzH6DGdLHw.png" style="height: 24px; width: 24px; display: block; margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;"/></td>
</tr>
  </table> 
  </div>  
</div>
<br>
<br>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In answer to your question, yes you can use javascript to dynamically insert elements after the page has loaded, however, if you simply want to use a span but a bug is preventing that particular tag then why not just use a different inline level element (`<i> or <label>`). After all thats all a span is.

**edit**

I've just had a look at your html markup and realised you are wrapping a load of block level elements like h3 and table inside your inline level span which is invalid html. I don't think this is actually a bug. Try it without the h3 and table inside and see if it still moves your span. Also why are you using a span here? If you want a container for the h3 and table to be inline then change the span to a div and set the div to `display: inline-block`

Comment: Thanks for that tip.  I tried all three and the corruption handed out by CKEditor is the same.  I can get around it by switching CKEditor to HTML mode, pasting in the unsullied HTML and then saving the page, but as soon as I edit the page again it opens in WYSIWYG mode and the HTML is trashed.

Comment: I think that's it!  I changed the <span> to a <div> and CKEditor doesn't mess with the HTML inside it.  I haven't needed to do anything to the `div` (i.e. no `display: inline-block` - it seems to work.  I'm cautiously optimistic.  I've updated the question with the code using `div`.

Comment: Glad it helped. It makes sense, if you don't need it to be inline then just use a div.